# Flutter - SQL how to return plain values

Tags: sql, sqlite, dart, flutter

In flutter, using the [sqflite package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/sqflite) I can create a database, using  this raw query... **A**

```
await db.execute('CREATE TABLE Article (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, title TEXT, description TEXT, url TEXT, urltoimage TEXT, publishedat TEXT)');`
```

I can then write data to the database like this... **B**

```
await txn.rawInsert('INSERT INTO Article(title, description, url, urltoimage, publishedat) VALUES("$title", "$description", "$url", "$urlToImage", "$publishedAt")');
```

Then I can retrieve this data as so... **C**

```
List<Map> title = await database.rawQuery('SELECT title FROM Article');
```

And finally use this data in flutter like this... **D**

```
Text('${title[index]}'),
```

When I use this method, I get this result upon execution of step **D**...

```
{title: Op-Ed: Does the Video Game Industry Really Need Blockchain?}
```

I'm aware that in properly returning this data, I'm missing a few steps.  What I really want instead is something like this... **E**

```
Op-Ed: Does the Video Game Industry Really Need Blockchain?
```

How could I get a result like **E** instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

type of query is `List<Map<String, dynamic>>`

you can return the result by getting a `key` like this

```
Text('${title[index]["title"]}'),
```

Comment: Thanks Ahmed I’ll take a look at this soon

Answer (score 1):

Your title variable is type of `List` of `Map` and the one element of list is in map for that what you see:

```
{title: Op-Ed: Does the Video Game Industry Really Need Blockchain?}
```

key is the `title` and value is `Op-Ed: Does the Video Game Industry Really Need Blockchain?`

So, in order to access the value you have to use your `title` key with list index:

ex: `title[0]['title']`

To get all element in list you can map like below:

```
Column(
  children: title.map((e) => {
    return Text(e['title'] ?? '');//if title is empty add empty string by ??
  }).toList();
),
```

or you can use `ListView.builder` or any..